# Problem with stacking convolutional and LSTM layer

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network, lstm

I'm trying to predict future stock returns for 200 days ahead based on the past returns using neural networks. I've already implemented network which consists of several LSTM layers and it's working ok:

```
lstm2=Sequential([
LSTM(50,input_shape=[None,1],return_sequences=True),
Dropout(0.2),
LSTM(50,return_sequences=True),
Dropout(0.2),
LSTM(50),
Dense(200)
])
```

However, when I try to stack a CONV1D layer on top of LSTM layers :

```
lstm_conv=Sequential([
Conv1D(filters=50,kernel_size=4,padding='valid',input_shape=[None,1]),
LSTM(50,return_sequences=True),
LSTM(50),
Dense(200)
])
```

I got an error in fit:

ValueError: Dimensions must be equal, but are 200 and 99 for '{{node mean_squared_error/SquaredDifference}} = SquaredDifference[T=DT_FLOAT](sequential_9/dense_9/BiasAdd, IteratorGetNext:1)' with input shapes: [?,200], [?,99].

The code for fit is:

```
lstm_conv.fit(xtrain,ytrain[:,3::2],epochs=10,validation_data=(xval,yval[:,3::2]))
```

The shape of my train X input is (1557, 20, 1), i.e I have 1557 train instances each going back to time by 20 and has one step per time (the series is univariate). For y it is (1557, 200)

I have no idea how to fix this, I've looked through several threads on internet but couldn't find a similar problem. Will appreciate any help.

Comment: In Conv1D, try to set `padding = 'causal'`

Comment: @Frightera that doesn't help unfortunately, the same error persists